# Multiplying time by integer in Codesys

Tags: codesys

I want to multiply a `TIME` variable by an integer. [Documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.14.0/en/_cds_operator_mul/#:%7E:text=%2C%20LREAL%2C-,TIME,-Feature%20in%20the) says that you can use * with `TIME` variables but when I try:

```
CYCLE_TIME          : TIME := T#5MS;
CYCLE_TIME_OFFSET   : TIME := CYCLE_TIME * 2;
```

Or

```
CYCLE_TIME          : TIME := T#5MS;
CYCLE_TIME_OFFSET   : TIME := CYCLE_TIME * TO_TIME(2);
```

Or

```
CYCLE_TIME          : TIME := T#5MS;
CYCLE_TIME_OFFSET   : TIME := (CYCLE_TIME * T#2MS);
```

I get an error I don't understand:

[image]

Can I multiply time by an integer, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While codesys does support TIME multiplication, strangely it seems to not support it at compile time (in the definition). For example:

```pascal
t1: TIME := T#5MS;
multiplier: UDINT := 2;
t2: TIME := t1 * multiplier;
```

Gives `C0073:  Cannot multiply multiple operands of type 'TIME'`, while

```pascal
t1: TIME := T#5MS;
multiplier: UDINT := 2;
t3: TIME := MUL(t1, multiplier);
```

Gives `C0007:  Expression expected instead of 'MUL'`.

Using any of the two above at runtime works as expected:

[image: Ladder Logic Program Example]

[image: Result of the Above Ladder Logic Program Example]

If you absolutely must multiply TIME in the definition phase, then you can always cast TIME to UDINT/DWORD (TIME <=> UDINT/DWORD, where 1 equals to 1 millisecond, so 12345 is 12 seconds and 345 milliseconds), do whatever operations you want, and then cast it back to TIME:

```pascal
t6: TIME := UDINT_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_UDINT(t1) * multiplier);
```

[image: Result of t6]